# How can I set edge jump over another edge?

Tags: javascript, diagram, cytoscape.js

I'm using `cytoscape.js` to draw diagram. I want to the edge jump over as picture below. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this [example](https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/edge-types/), cytpscape.js does not support this kind of edge-line. In order to get this feature into cytoscape.js, consider creating a feature request in the official [repository](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js).